# How to efficiently check and add if an element does not exist in a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a huge nested list which its elements are word strings with the following form:

```
[[0,'+','the','+','quick','+','brown','+','fox','+','jumps','over','+','the','+','lazy','+','dog','+',908]
...,
['Now','+','is','+', 'the','+', 'time','+', 'for','+', 'all','+', 67,'+', 'men']]
```

However, I identified that there are some elements with no `+` separator. For example, in sublist one:

```
[0,'+','the','+','quick','+','brown','+','fox','+','jumps','over','+','the','+','lazy','+','dog','+',908]
```

Between `'jumps','over'` is missing `+`. For large nested lists with long sublists, which would the most efficient way of adding the `+` separator between elements with no separator?

The expected output should look like this:

```
[[0,'+','the','+','quick','+','brown','+','fox','+','jumps','+','over','+','the','+','lazy','+','dog','+',908]
    ...,
    ['Now','+','is','+', 'the','+', 'time','+', 'for','+', 'all','+', 67,'+', 'men']]
```

Comment: This looks like a trivial problem, have you tried anything yet? Isn't it easier to eliminate all `'+'`s and process the list accordingly instead?

Comment: What if there is `+,+,+` in the original list.

Comment: Since you're using a list, there isn't a really efficient way to do it.  Iterate over the list and compare every item to its neighbor.  Be sure to iterate from the _end_ of the list and go backwards, so when you insert a plus sign, you don't upset the index values of the remaining list items.

Comment: It should be normalized to one `+` @ComplicatedPhenomenon

Comment: Of course, thats the trivial solution. However, Is there any other way of doing it? @Selcuk

Comment: @JohnGordon could you show how to compare all the items with its forward neighbor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit greedy:

```
cleansed_lists = [[word for word in sentence if word != '+'] for sentence in nested_list]
result = []
for sentence in cleansed_lists:
    new_list = ['+'] * (2 * len(sentence) - 1)
    new_list[::2] = sentence
    result.append(new_list)
```

**Time Complexity:**

Suppose `N` is the length of your outer list and `n` is the average length of each of your inner lists (your sentences).

*Line 1*: We iterate through the outer list once and each inner list once, using *O(1)* operations (i.e. `if word != '+'`). Thus, Line 1 has a time complexity of *O(n*N)*.

*Lines 3-6*: We iterate through our outer list once (Line 3), the *equivalent* of a list twice the size of our inner list (Line 4), and every other element of a list twice the size of our inner list (Line 5). This produces a time complexity of *O(N*(2n + n))*, which simplifies down to *O(n*N)*.

```
= O(n*N) + O(N*(2n+n))
= O(n*N) + O(N*3n)
= O(n*N) + O(N*n)
= O(n*N)
```

Thus, the final complexity is *O(n*N)*.

Comment: how efficient is this?

Comment: @anon Added time complexity breakdown

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [[0,'+','the','+','quick','+','brown','+','fox','+','jumps','over','+','the','+','lazy','+','dog','+',908],
['Now','+','is','+', 'the','+', 'time','+', 'for','+', 'all','+', 67,'+', 'men']]

x = [[i for i in item if i != '+'] for item in x]
print([sum([[a,b] for a, b in zip(item, ['+' for _ in range(len(item))])], []) for item in x ])
```

Output

```
[[0, '+', 'the', '+', 'quick', '+', 'brown', '+', 'fox', '+', 'jumps', '+', 'over', '+', 'the', '+', 'lazy', '+', 'dog', '+', 908, '+'], ['Now', '+', 'is', '+', 'the', '+', 'time', '+', 'for', '+', 'all', '+', 67, '+', 'men', '+']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried two methods but with no large nested lists:

```py
data = [0, '+', 'the', '+', 'quick', '+', 'brown', '+', 'fox', '+',
        'jumps', 'over', '+', 'the', '+', 'lazy', '+', 'dog', '+', 908]


def func_1():
    for i in range(1, len(data), 2):
        if data[i] != '+':
            data.insert(i, '+')


def func_2():
    real_data = [val for val in data if val != '+']
    spliter = '+'*len(real_data)
    [i for ab in zip(real_data, spliter) for i in ab][:-1]


%timeit func_1()
%timeit func_2()
```

And the final result is:

```
981 ns ± 17.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
3.24 µs ± 101 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Maybe you can have a try~Good luck!